# What are the dangers of assigning to a free variable in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Adding `(setq foo 1)` to the code without defining the variable `foo` using `defvar` will result in the following warning generated by Emacs byte-compiler:

```
assignment to free variable `foo'
```

What are the dangers associated with assigning to such free variable without prior definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs Lisp uses [Dynamic Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html) by default, so when you write

```
(defun my-fun-1 (...)
  ...
  (setq foo 1)
  ...)
```

and get your warning, the code is equivalent to having `(defvar foo)` before the `defun`.

This means that the `my-fun-1` above shares the value of `foo` with

```
(defun maybe-start-ww3 ()
   (when (= 1 foo)
     (launch-missiles)))
```

this is not always bad; much ELisp legacy code uses such globals to pass state. However, this is a *very* bad style, if you use the same variable name (e.g., `date`) for these purposes in two unrelated places, the consequences could be unpredictable.

In short, if you use the free variable in a single place, there is no reason not to bind it.
If you use it to pass state, you should `defvar` it and use a long name which is not likely to be used by someone else - and you should refactor your code to avoid that.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, not using defvar is basically harmless if the goal is to set (or define and set) a global variable, e.g. inside a package, a variable with a long, package specific name.

Comment: Indeed, harmless but stupid. Remember, you write code for others (and yourself next year!) to _read_ it, not just for computer to execute it. By adding the `defvar` you are adding a crucial piece of documentation.

Comment: Fully agree. My situation was a bit different however. The goal was to "generate" global variables inside a macro with dynamically generated names. `defvar` does not evaluate the symbol given to it, which made using it not possible in this context.

Comment: Even in your situation there is a way to avoid the warning (in CL, you can use `gensym` & `declare` &c). Please ask a separate question.

Comment: @And: indeed `defvar` doesn't evaluate the symbol given to it, but you don't need that anyway, since instead your macro can return something of the form `(progn (defvar <foo>) ...)` so you can construct the defvar which will then be run once the macro-expanded code is run.

Comment: The warning is just a warning, after all; but polluting your global name space is a bad habit, and often enough, you actually get the warning because you misspelled a properly defined variable, which is of course also useful during development.